# How do you maintain changes made by VisualState triggers after setting another VisualState?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uwp

Not sure if am framing the question right. So please bear with me if I'm expecting something absurd. I am building a C#/XAML win10 UWP application following the MVVM pattern. 
I've some visual states defined for handling wider screens and also some for running some animations. The problem am facing is that, when the visual state to run the animation is called using the VisualStateManager's GoToState method, the setters effected by the VisualState containing the adaptive triggers are lost. 
Here's the sample code:

```
//Defining my grid here
<Grid x:Name="gridNewDrawing" Margin="4">
<Button x:Name="Confirm" Click="Button_Confirm_Click" Width="180" MaxWidth="220" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="StaticResource StyleButtonGeneral}"/>
<Button x:Name="Cancel" Click="Button_Cancel_Click" Width="180" MaxWidth="220" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="StaticResource StyleButtonGeneral}"/>
</Grid>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>                
                <VisualState x:Name="WideLayoutTrigger">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="gridNewDrawing.Margin" Value="16" />                        
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="AnimationState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Cancel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                                     
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

When the width is above 640px; the margin on the gridNewDrawing switches to 16; but when I explicitly call the animation using

> GoToState("AnimationState")

The margin on the grid defaults to 4 once again. Is there any way I can have the changes made by the adaptivetrigger persist when setting other visual styles?

Comment: Try doing everything in code without xaml.

Comment: The state AnimationState does not define any margin so it takes the default value that was 4. If you want you can set the Storyboard in resources instead of an state and invoke the storyboard when you need. Or add also the setter in the AnimationState depending on your purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margin of the grid changes to default again because your `VisualState` are in same `VisualStateGroup`. You can set the `AnimationState` in another `VisualStateGroup` to maintain changes made by the `AdaptiveTrigger`.

See the **Remarks** of [VisualStateGroup class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstategroup).

> The set of visual states within each VisualStateGroup should be mutually exclusive in the group. In other words, the control should be using exactly one of the visual states from each of its defined VisualStateGroup groups at all times. Whenever there's a case where a control is intended to be simultaneously in two states, make sure that the two states are in different groups.

So apply the following code should get what you want:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="WideLayoutTrigger">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="gridNewDrawing.Margin" Value="16" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OtherStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="AnimationState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Cancel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```